# jquery slideshow with text as well as images

Tags: jquery

I must have looked at hundreds by now ... I want a slide show that will show (for example) three 900 x 300 pixel images - one after the other with each one on the screen for say 30 seconds. But, on top of the pictures, somewhere, I want to include some text.

It sounds simple enough but everything I look at is either way more complicated or has navagation buttons and things. I just want a nice clean - 3 pictures, with some text on top (must be text though, not text as part of the image as this often looks rancid) - with no borders, or buttons etc.

Can anyone point me at a simple jquery based slideshow that allows this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any 900x300 images but this should do what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/YwUG7/23/

I set the timeout to 3 seconds there. Just add another 0 for 30 seconds.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. If I create, for example:
#caption1
#caption2
#caption3

so that I can use css to position the caption in different places, different sizes depending on where on the image I want it to appear ... I see how the loop works to change the images - how can I get the css caption to change too?

Thanks very much for your help on this.

Comment: Again, thanks for that. I didn't realise you should or could 'accept' answers. This is a great site but I find it unintuitive to use.

Comment: Is it possible to add some sort of transition between images - to the code you have written?
I have looked at some image transition tutorials and they all seem to be based on using multiple img tags with the images all in the same position - and then transitioning between them.
Is this necessary? Your code with one img tag and the images in an array seems much neater to me. Can transitions be added to this?

Comment: I tried adding:

    $("#image").fadeIn();
    setInterval($("#image").fadeOut(), 5000);

and extending the interval that the images are refreshed to 10 seconds - hoping each image would appear for 5 seconds, fade out and then the next one would appear 5 seconds later (just to test) but the image appears and fades out immediately.